# Store key value pairs in Moodle

Tags: php, ajax, chat, yui, moodle

I am adding a feature to the Moodle chat to allow teachers to disable students typing in a chat.
I have a dropdown in the chat area which the teacher can select to allow or not allow typing.
The value of this dropdown is sent via an Ajax request.
I need a way to store this value and then retrieve it in all chat windows (for that particular chat of course) to determine is if I should enable or disable to message input area.

I have been looking the the built in cache API but that is not suited and I cant get it to work
http://fossies.org/dox/moodle-2.8.6/md_cache_README.html

I am developing on Moodle 2.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit more digging and cool off, I figured out the solution.

First off, you have to create a definition for in the `/mod/[[modname]]/db/caches.php` as described in http://fossies.org/dox/moodle-2.8.6/md_cache_README.html,

An simple example would be

```
$definitions = array(
    'chatdata' => array(
        'mode' => cache_store::MODE_APPLICATION
    )
);
```

In you module file, you can do the following to start storing and retrieving data.

```
$cache = cache::make_from_params(cache_store::MODE_APPLICATION, 'core', 'chatdata'); //Declare a handle for the cache
$result = $cache->set('key', 'value'); //Store value
$cache->get('key'); //Retrieve value
```